# Make my Android Activity look like a ViewPager

Tags: android

I am using a ViewPager in my Android app. On clicking certain pages in the ViewPager, some details are to be shown, which I show in an Activity. I want the activity to look similar to my viewpager to give a consistent look to my app(with the activity name in the pagerstrip). Is it possible to get this done. Kindly help.

Comment: Thanks. I have actually implemented a Fragment and a ViewPager for one of my activity. The issue is that I have one more activity of mine which I want to look like a ViewPager page.

Comment: Inside ViewPager Give Fragment as child. and then one Fragment will behave like one activity. I had prepared some material to post this about on my blog. Soon i will post it